# Copy HTML with CSS to Libre Office

Tags: html, css, libreoffice

I have an HTML page styled with CSS. I would like to copy it to Libre Office Writer, so that I can edit it. However, when I copy & paste, only the HTML is copied, without the style. I tried "Paste Special - HTML" and got the same results.

I use Libre Office 3.5.3.2 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Are you copying the HTML code or the content from the page in a browser?

Comment: I copy from the browser and paste into Libre Office.

Comment: looking for that exact solution here too, but with impress ...

Answer (score 5):

It seems that the style of `<body>` is discarded and only inline CSS is used when you copy and paste. For me, copying from Firefox and pasting in LibreOffice, the following HTML didn't retain formatting:

```
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    body { font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; }
    span { color: red; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  Lorem ipsum <span>dolor</span> sit amet.
</body>
```

and

```
<body style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px;">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</body>
```

But the following worked as expected:

```
<body>
  <div style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px;">
    Lorem ipsum <span style="color: red;" >dolor</span> sit amet.
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: OK, so how can I copy the style from the CSS file to the LibreOffice document?

Answer (score -3):

Just hit ctrl+u on the browser page. A saperate window wil b opened which contains the entire HTML script..Now in that HTML, go to "link" tag  and click on the underlined href....Your desired css file would be opened in a new window..copy the entire(ctrl+A) or selected styles and enjoy...

Comment: That will put the raw CSS source (well, some of it… maybe, it might be embedded or split across multiple files) on the clipboard. How do you apply it to the LibreOffice document then?